# What is the word equivalent to "dine with me" for lunch?

Tags: word-choice

While "*Would you dine with me tonight?*" is to eat dinner with me. 
How can I ask some one to have lunch with me?

Comment: ***Lunch*** is also a verb.

Comment: The verb "dine" is not limited to only the evening meal. And there are some varieties of English where "dinner" means the biggest meal of the day, even if that is lunch.

Comment: In fact there are many restaurants called "diners" in the U.S. that are open for breakfast and lunch only, _not_ for dinner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've answered your question in your question. The simplest, easiest way to say it is:

> ***Would (or will) you have lunch with me?***

or:

> ***Would (or will) you go to lunch with me?***

You could technically say:

> ***Would you lunch with me?***

But it's a rather stilted way to phrase it.

Comment: So can I just replace the 'dine' with lunch and say "Would you lunch with me today?"

Comment: You could, although it's a little awkward to say it that way. "Have lunch" or "eat lunch" is more natural.

Comment: I don't think “Would you lunch with me today?” is really any more stilted than “Would you dine with me tonight?”. They're both fairly old-fashioned and a bit stilted, but one not considerable more so than the other.

Comment: Indeed. Agreed.

Comment: "Get lunch" would also be pretty natural sounding.  You could even say "(do you) want to get lunch?" but that may be a little more casual than OP is looking for.

Answer (score 6):

It's something of shibboleth today but I often heard people in New York's pulsating business culture in 1980's and 1990's end a meeting with the refrain, "**Let's do lunch sometime"**! My take on this is that it was a meaningless gesture of the burgeoning business culture post-1970's, a revival that relied heavily at a certain level on networking and the "business" lunch. It was a mistake to believe that this was a sincere invitation to lunch; rather it was understood as a way of signalling the possibility of a convivial business lunch, an opportunity to negotiate or close a business deal that might crop up in the future.

It's no coincidence that New York's once great restaurant, the Four Seasons, gave us the expression "power lunch", the great and the good of Manhattan's business elite jockeying for the allocation of the best tables in the Grill Room if you were A-list, the Pool Room the natural habitat of the also rans.

Comment: How is that a shibboleth? _Do lunch_ is still fairly common in my experience, mainly among socialites who generally have no desire whatsoever to do lunch with whomever they're talking to.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet For me the expression was born of its time and place,  a buzzword of its era that saw the Big Apples's re-emergence in the wake of a business and cultural bankruptcy that blighted the city in the1970's. I hear it less often nowadays.

Comment: That's an interesting and authentic piece of observation taken from real life if ever I heard one.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re interested in just a word, and not a word–for–word equivalent of the phrase, then **“Lunch”** with a quizzical look on you face should do the trick, as well.

Comment: Quite so! But if you really want to elicit an equally quizzical look in reply, then try saying "luncheon?" in response. That should also do the trick, what?

Comment: @Peter Point: In summary, if the person harbors no desire to elicit such a quizzical look, then it should do the trick, especially in an informal setting.

Comment: You have a point! I harbor the desire for yesteryear when luncheon was a more a formal and satisfying gustatory experience.

Comment: I concur, especially with the part that alludes to the mannerisms of the yesteryear; not all of them deserved to dissipate without a trace.